# TokenInterface $token->getUser() doesnt bring back an object

Tags: symfony, entity, api-platform.com, symfony4-voter

I am making CheeseListing RESTful API with ApiPlatform.

I made a voter for my CheeseListing object:

```
class CheeseListingVoter extends Voter
{

...

protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token)
{
    $user = $token->getUser();
    // if the user is anonymous, do not grant access
    if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
    return false;
}

/** $var CheeseListing $subject */

// ... (check conditions and return true to grant permission) ...
switch ($attribute) {
    case 'EDIT':
        if($subject->getOwner() === $user){
            return true;
        }
...
```

Why does `$subject->getOwner() === $user` bring back true when `$token->getUser()` is an object and `$subject->getOwner()` is an Iri "/api/users/1"

Comment: I'm gonna ask the stupid questions: $subject->getOwner() being an uri sounds unexpected, are you sure? I mean, if it is actually true, then one would expect both to be objects or both to be uri or bot to be null. soooo ... how do you know?

Answer (score 0):

Answer : Even though ApiResource's `/api/CheeseListing/` Get Endpoint returns an user's Iri :
like

```
{
    "title": "..."
    "owner": "/api/users/1"
}
```

Owner field is actually an object. ApiResource have it's own feature for converting Iri's to objects and vice versa.

Same thing applies when posting `/api/CheeseListing`, you get the following :

```
{
    "title": "..."
    "owner": "/api/users/1"
}
```

It actually converts from `"/api/users/1"` to User object

Answer (score -1):

Don't use if() and try with the id because in your entity user I don't thinkk you have a getOwner().
Try this :

```php
switch ($attribute) {
    case 'EDIT':
        return $subject->getId() === $user->getId()
```